# ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider() throwing exception, on Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm writing a shared library in .NET 5.0 that needs to make some javascript available to its clients.

I have the javascript in a .js file I'm including as an embedded resource:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  [...]
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="5.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  [...]
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript/MyFile.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And I've created an extension method on IApplicationBuilder that uses ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider() to map the embedded resource into the website's routing:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder MapMyFiles(this IApplicationBuilder app, string localPath)
{
    app.Map(localPath, builder =>
    {
        var provider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(
            assembly: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "JavaScript");
        builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = provider
        });
    });

    return app;
}
```

And then in Startup.Configure(), I use the extension method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // ...

    app.MapMyFiles("/myfiles");
}
```

And here's the thing - I originally wrote this running on Linux, and on Linux it works exactly as I'd expect.

But now that I have it working, I wanted to test on Windows 10, and in Windows 10 I'm getting an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> Message [string]: "Invalid path: 'JavaScript'"
> Source [string]: "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded"
> HResult [int]: -2146233079

I'd not have been surprised if Windows had worked and Linux had not, because Windows is case-insensitive and Linux is not, and if I'd used inconsistent casing. But it makes no sense the other way, and I'm pretty sure I'm using consistent casing in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of yet another Windows vs Linux difference; the path separator.
Windows uses `\` instead of `/`.

Change the path of the embedded resource to:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="JavaScript\MyFile.js" />
```

---

To make this work on both operating systems, you might use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine).
Note: I couldn't try this on Linux.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="$([System.IO.Path]::Combine('JavaScript','MyFile.js'))" />
```

---

**UPDATE**

As from your comment on this answer, `\` seems to work for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: How do I get this assembly to work on either Windows or Linux?

Comment: @JeffDege You might use `Path.Combine`, see updated answer.

Comment: Using Path.Combine() worked on Linux.
But, oddly enough, so did using '\'..